# Expectation of the product of a stopping time and a stochastic process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, expected-value, stopping-times, stochastic-differential-equations

$S_t$ is a geometric Brownian motion, i.e., $dS_t = \mu S_t dt + \sigma S_t dW_t.$

> Does the following hold:
>
> $$
> \mathbb{E}_t (S_T \mathbb{1}_{\left\{ \tau (\delta) < T \right\}}) = \mathbb{E}_t (S_T) \mathbb{E}_t (\mathbb{1}_{\left\{ \tau (\delta) < T \right\}}) $$ where $\tau$ is a stopping time and defined as $$\tau (\delta) = \inf\left\{0<t<T: S_t < \delta\right\}?
> $$

I only have some rough intuitions regarding the independence between $S_T$ and $\mathbb{1}_{\tau (\delta) <T }$: $S_T$ is at the end point and its distribution is independent of the path leading to $S_T$, while $\mathbb{1}_{\tau (\delta) <T }$ is pretty much dependent on the path, therefore, I thought the equation holds.

Comment: What have you tried? Add that in your question

Comment: I only have some rough intuitions regarding the independence between $S_T$ and $\mathbb{1}_{\left\{\tau (\delta) < T\right\}}$: $S_T$ is a at the end point and its distribution is independent of the path leading to $S_T$, while $\mathbb{1}_{\left\{\tau (\delta)< T\right\}}$ is pretty much dependent on the path, therefore, I thought the equation holds.

Comment: If you know $S_t$ was very small for some $t < T$, would you expect $S_T$ to be large or small?  Taking the most extreme case, if you knew $S_t = 0$ for some $t < T$, what would you expect $S_T$ to be?

Comment: The statement doesn't hold true. The problem is related to the joint distribution of $(W_t, \max_{s <t} W_s)$.